# Create a sequence between multiple functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sequence, user-defined-functions

QUESTION: How to create a sequence between multiple functions?

I have various functions which create xml data and  each function can create multiple sets of "Party" nodes. All of the functions start of with the same parent node. I want the output to look like the following where each party regardless of what function it comes from has the continuing sequence number. DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
<PARTIES>
   <PARTY SequenceNumber="1" label="PARTY_1">
   ...
   <PARTY SequenceNumber="2" label="PARTY_2">
   ...
   <PARTY SequenceNumber="3" label="PARTY_3">
   ...
</PARTIES>
```

Right now I am outputting my xml through a function that returns xml, and the functions I want to sequence are grouped together under PARTIES node:

```
SELECT  [dbo].[GetFunction1Xml](@Id),
        [dbo].[GetFunction2Xml](@Id),
        [dbo].[GetFunction3Xml](@Id)
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('PARTIES'), TYPE
```

Each function collects information from different places and could look like this:

```
ALTER GetFunction1XML
...
RETURNS XML (
SELECT  [label] = 'PARTY_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))  
        [Var1] = ....,
        [Var2] = ....,
FROM [Table]
FOR XML PATH('PARTY'), TYPE)
END;
```

I attempted to use a Sequence however it is not allowed in user-defined functions.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Party_Seq
AS INTEGER
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
NO CYCLE;
```

I also attempted the following inside each function since it works if I were to have two parties in the same function connected by a UNION ALL. However it restarts to PARTY_1 everytime since all the parties are in different functions.

```
SELECT  [@label] = 'PARTY_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))
```

So for example if i were to replace 2 functions with 1 generic one it would look like this and it print out the information correctly; however I have way too many functions to do this.

```
ALTER GetGenericFunctionXML
...
RETURNS XML (

SELECT  [@seq] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        [@label] = 'PARTY_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))  
        [Var1] = [food].[fruit],
        [Var2] = [food].[meat]

FROM ( SELECT 'Apple' AS [fruit],
              'Bacon' AS [meat]
        FROM [Table1]

       UNION ALL

       SELECT 'Grape',
              'Pork'
        FROM [Table2] 
     ) AS [food]

FOR XML PATH('PARTY'), TYPE)
END;
```

Output:

```
 <PARTIES>
   <PARTY SequenceNumber="1" label="PARTY_1">
     <Var1>Apple</Var1>
     <Var2>Bacon</Var2>
   <PARTY SequenceNumber="2" label="PARTY_2">
     <Var1>Grape</Var1>
     <Var2>Pork</Var2>
   <PARTY SequenceNumber="3" label="PARTY_3">
 </PARTIES>
```

I also tried passing a parameter to the functions but since they are functions they can't output the value (I believe only stored procedures can do this. Correct me if I'm wrong.).

Comment: You should post sample data and the code from your UDF.  Without those it's not really clear what you have going on.  I have no idea how you are getting 11, 12 and 13 for your ID's.

Comment: @btberry Those were example values. I have changed them to 1, 2, and 3 above. That is what I want to achieve but I haven't been able to.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a UDF? A scalar UDF like you have here will always have performance issues and I just don't see what you are doing that makes it desirable or needed. Put that code in in a cte or subquery or something. If there is some reason you really have to do the UDF or if it's just a fun puzzle to try to solve please explain.

Comment: @btberry No there is no reason. I didn't know there were performance issues to it. I would rather do what has better performance and works. So you're saying if I wrap all that inside a cte would be better?

Comment: @btberry I do not agree... There are severe performance issues with *multi-statement-table-valued-functions* (the syntax with `AS BEGIN...END`), but a scalar function returning one single XML should be OK. One most be aware, that the calls are not fully inlined and therefore the optimizer might not find the best execution plan. This depends on the kind of data you are pulling for your XML...

Comment: @Shnugo you can agree or not, but you are incorrect.  Scalar UDF's have always been broken in terms of performance.  Just do a quick Google search on 'sql server scalar function performance' and you will find tons of info like [this one](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx) or [another one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4100/how-to-find-udfs-causing-sql-server-performance-issues/).  If you must use a function, the only type without a performance hit are inline table functions.

Comment: @btberry, Okay... In general you are right and I am - if you read through some of my earlier answers one of the knights of *ad-hoc-sql*, of *inlined-TVF* and *set-based-code* fighting against *procedural thinking*, `CURSORs` and `LOOPs` :-) But: We are talking about XML. This issue is - assumeably - some kind of external interface or reporting issue, hence some final sugar candy. If you are really concerned about performance, you would not use XML and `FLWOR`-logic...

Comment: @Shnugo I would never use a SQL Server scalar function for any reason because there are inherent performance issues and no upside to speak of.  Even if it's just to return a static string, I wouldn't do it because there are always better options (such as a single row inline table function) that won't leave you hosed when someone else comes along and makes that static return more dynamic.  This is something I discussed specifically with Itzik Ben-Gan a few years ago and I very much agree with his perspective on the matter.  You can do what you want but I don't agree with the use of scalar UDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might solve this with [FLWOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f1() RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    '<PARTY label="PARTY_f1a">
          <Var1>f1a.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f1a.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>
     <PARTY label="PARTY_f1b">
          <Var1>f1b.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f1b.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>
     <PARTY label="PARTY_f1c">
          <Var1>f1c.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f1c.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>';
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f2() RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    '<PARTY label="PARTY_f2a">
          <Var1>f2a.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f2a.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>
     <PARTY label="PARTY_f2b">
          <Var1>f2b.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f2b.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>';
END
GO
```

--The query starts here

```
WITH AllPartyNodes AS
(
    SELECT
        (
        SELECT dbo.f1()
              ,dbo.f2()
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ) AS AllTogether
)
,NumberedSequences AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SequenceNr
           ,The.Party.query('.') AS TheNode
    FROM AllPartyNodes
    CROSS APPLY AllTogether.nodes('/PARTY') AS The(Party)
)
SELECT TheNode.query('let $p:=/PARTY[1]
                      let $lbl:=$p/@label
                      let $nr:=sql:column("SequenceNr")
                      return
                         <PARTY seq="{$nr}" label="{$lbl}" >
                         {$p/*}
                         </PARTY>'
                        ) AS [node()]
FROM NumberedSequences
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('PARTIES')

GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.f1;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.f2;
```

### UPDATE Another approach

You might extract the data and rebuild it.

Put this below my "NumberedSequence" CTE

```
,TheData AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,TheNode.value('(PARTY/@label)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Label
          ,TheNode.query('PARTY/*') AS InnerNodes 
    FROM NumberedSequences
)
SELECT SequenceNr AS [@seq]
      ,Label AS [@label]
      ,InnerNodes AS [node()]
FROM TheData
FOR XML PATH('PARTY'),ROOT('PARTIES')
```

### UPDATE 2

The same with the main query as function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f1() RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    '<PARTY label="PARTY_f1a">
          <Var1>f1a.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f1a.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>
     <PARTY label="PARTY_f1b">
          <Var1>f1b.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f1b.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>
     <PARTY label="PARTY_f1c">
          <Var1>f1c.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f1c.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>';
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f2() RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    '<PARTY label="PARTY_f2a">
          <Var1>f2a.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f2a.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>
     <PARTY label="PARTY_f2b">
          <Var1>f2b.1</Var1>
          <Var2>f2b.2</Var2>
     </PARTY>';
END
GO

--The main query as function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f3() RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result XML;

WITH AllPartyNodes AS
(
    SELECT
        (
        SELECT dbo.f1()
              ,dbo.f2()
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ) AS AllTogether
)
,NumberedSequences AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SequenceNr
           ,The.Party.query('.') AS TheNode
    FROM AllPartyNodes
    CROSS APPLY AllTogether.nodes('/PARTY') AS The(Party)
)
SELECT @Result=
(
    SELECT TheNode.query('let $p:=/PARTY[1]
                          let $lbl:=$p/@label
                          let $nr:=sql:column("SequenceNr")
                          return
                             <PARTY seq="{$nr}" label="{$lbl}" >
                             {$p/*}
                             </PARTY>'
                            ) AS [node()]
    FROM NumberedSequences
    FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('PARTIES'), TYPE
)
RETURN @Result;
END
GO

SELECT dbo.f3();
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.f1;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.f2;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.f3;
```

Comment: I tried running this but I get a couple of errors. In NumberedSequences [AllTogether] is an invalid object name. Isn't it because it's outside the scope of the previous SELECT?

Comment: @DRockClimber, did you copy the whole lot, function creation and queries?

Comment: I ran your query in a new query window and it worked. Then I put it inside an Alter Function and it created a lot of errors. I think it has to do with that. I have `Returns XML AS BEGIN RETURN (With AllPartyNodes AS...` and this creates an error in the With statement. @Shnugo

Comment: Wow thanks it worked! Now I just have to build on that. Hey I've been looking for what the $ as well as the :=  operator does but I can't seem to find it besides the link you posted. I want to understand what those do. Do you have any other documentation for it?

Comment: Forgot to tag in above. @Shnugo

Comment: As mentioned in my comments on the original question, do not use scalar functions if you care about performance.